# How to get URLs sorted by most Facebook Likes based on my appId?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Just as the question says, is there a way to get an array of URLs on my domain sorted by most Facebook Likes? I have a Facebook appId if that helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use FQL, like this:

```
SELECT url, like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url IN ('http://www.url1.com', 'http://www.url2.com')
```

You can't get it sorted from facebook, you must do that manually later.

Here are some useful links, hope it helps:

http://sudocode.net/article/368/how-to-get-the-access-token-for-a-facebook-application-in-php/
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Comment: Link is now http://codecri.me/article/368/how-to-get-the-access-token-for-a-facebook-application-in-php/